# Filter AngularJS Json file

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I tryed to filter my ng-repeat List like this:

My JSON lokks like this:http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.5.1/data/en_US/champion.json

Here ist the JS Fiddle

```js
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])

.controller("ListCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.5.1/data/en_US/champion.json").then(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data.data.data;
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="suche">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="champ in data">
            <h1>{{champ.name}}</h1>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why  you are using data.data.data ?  data.data can serve your cause as per Ur Json structure

Comment: let me know  whether that is working or not i can create a plunker in angularjs with your sample json for filtering

Comment: I use Data.data.data because i want to show the Champions Data like Champion.name

Comment: If you want to help ne with a plunker sample it would be nice

Comment: Can you provide sample data instead of Bulk json?

Comment: No Problem. Just an example how to Filter that Objekt List

Comment: Here you can test it out. http://play.ionic.io/app/f8b16b89f73f

Comment: @DanielSogl from filtering what you means ? can you please elaborate ? on what criteria you want to filter ?

Comment: I jsut want to filter by the champion names.